# Xcode can't find audio file (swift 3)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to have a button play a sound when I push a button. I made the same app on my friend's computer and it worked fine, but now when I do it, it gives me an error saying "Unable to find sound file with name 'XD.mp3'" (XD is the name of the file I imported into Xcode) I've tried moving the file to different areas of the project, changed the file type to m4a, and deleted and re-referenced the file, but nothing works.

[image]

The sound class supports mp3 and m4a files, and Xcode is only giving me the error during runtime; it's not an issue in the code (I think).

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Make sure that you are copying your file inside `build phases` in your Xcodeproj file.

Comment: Don't post an image. Please update your question with your code as text (copy and pasted and formatted properly). Also copy and paste the error as text. This makes it much easier to read and reference when answering.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you are copying your file inside `build phases/copy bundle resource` in your Xcodeproj file (the blue one).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Then clean your project and delete derived data

Comment: @Matthew McDonnell Check your spelling where you calling the file !remember it is key sensitive!

Comment: @MatthewMcDonnell then sorry I don't know

Answer (score 0):

You need import the files in the option called "Build Phases".

[image]

Comment: @Moritz i don't understand your question

Comment: ok, sorry. 
I just wanted to complement the answer, because the same thing happened to me, and I wanted to point out that uploading the files would work.